# Find all arrays that includes certain id Postgres

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I store adjacency tree in table. I wrote a recursive Common Table expression to find all ascendants for each node in the tree. 
So when I write `SELECT * FROM TREE;`

I get this:

```
 id |   ancestors   
----+---------------
  0 | {} <- ROOT
  1 | {0}
  2 | {0}
  4 | {0}
 19 | {0}
 45 | {0}
  3 | {0,1}
  5 | {0,4}
  6 | {0,4}
  8 | {0,4}
 11 | {0,1}
 22 | {0,2}
  7 | {0,4,5}
  9 | {0,4,6}
```

I want to get the amount of all descendants for each node in the tree, so for each unique id I want to find number of arrays in ancestors column that contains such id.

I can do it manually, but only for one id:

```
SELECT count(*) from tree
WHERE 0 = any(tree.ancestors);
```

For this query, if node with id = 0 is the root, it should give me amount of all nodes minus 1 in the tree.

I tried to write something like this:

```
SELECT count(*) from tree
WHERE id = any(tree.ancestors)
group by id;
```

But it actually returns 0 rows.

Answer (score 1):

You want to search the whole tree for each `id`, it's a self-join with a condition:

```
with tree(id, ancestors) as (
values
    (0, '{}'::int[]),
    (1, '{0}'),
    (2, '{0}'),
    (4, '{0}'),
    (19, '{0}'),
    (45, '{0}'),
    (3, '{0,1}'),
    (5, '{0,4}'),
    (6, '{0,4}'),
    (8, '{0,4}'),
    (11, '{0,1}'),
    (22, '{0,2}'),
    (7, '{0,4,5}'),
    (9, '{0,4,6}')
)

select t1.id, count(t2.*)
from tree t1
join tree t2 on t1.id = any(t2.ancestors)
group by 1
order by 1

 id | count 
----+-------
  0 |    13
  1 |     2
  2 |     1
  4 |     5
  5 |     1
  6 |     1
(6 rows)
```

Note that you should use `left join` if you want to get all `ids` (with those that don't  appear in `ancestors`).